# Создать новый файл, каждая строка которого получается из соответствующей строки исходного файла перестановкой слов в обратном порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан текстовый файл. Создать новый файл, каждая строка которого получается из соответствующей строки исходного файла перестановкой слов в обратном порядке.

```py
file1 = open('test_2.txt', 'r')
text2 = file1.readlines()
for lines in range(0, len(text2)):
    text2[lines]=text2[lines].split()[::-1]

new_file = open("res.txt", "w")
new_file.write(text2)
```

А вот записать не получается, говорит что должна быть сторока , а не список.

> TypeError: must be str, not list.

Суть ошибки я понимаю, не могу понять как исправить. Подскажите.Спасибо.

Comment: Делал так, но некотрые пробелы пропали.
file1 = open('test_2.txt', 'r')
new_file = open("res.txt", "w")

text2 = file1.readlines()
for lines in range(0, len(text2)):
    text2[lines]=text2[lines].split()[::-1]
for lines in range(0, len(text2)):
    text2[lines]=' '.join(text2[lines])
    new_file.write(text2[lines])

Comment: Оставил так, похоже на правду....
# file1 = open('test_2.txt', 'r')
# new_file = open("res.txt", "w")
#
# text2 = file1.readlines()
#
# for lines in range(0, len(text2)):
#     text2[lines]=' '.join(text2[lines].split()[::-1])
#     new_file.write(text2[lines])

Answer (score 1):

Если открываете файл таким способом `new_file = open("res.txt", "w")`, то нужно не забыть его закрывать `new_file.close()`. Но лучше воспользоваться менеджером контекста `with as`

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.readlines()

for lines in range(0, len(text)):
   text[lines]=text[lines].split()[::-1]

with open("res.txt", "w") as new_file:
    for line in text:
        line = " ".join(line) + "\n" # преобразуем список в строку и добавляем конец строки
        new_file.write(line) # пишем в файл
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Логика та же, но короче

```py
with open("text.txt") as file:
    text = [line.split()[::-1] for line in file.readlines()]

with open("res.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join([" ".join(line) for line in text]))
```